# Changing the value of a pointer but keeping the address

Tags: c, pointers

I want to write a program which changes the value in the address a pointer points to but keep the address the same. I wrote a small program to test it but I'm having some problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *entry1, int *entry2, int length)

{
  int i,temp;

  for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
      temp = *entry1[i];
      *entry1[i] = *entry2[i];
      *entry2[i] = temp;
    }
}

int main()

{
  int length=5, i;

  int *entry1 = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
  int *entry2 = malloc(length * sizeof(int));

  for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
      entry1[i] = i + 1;
      entry2[i] = length - i;

    }
swap(entry1, entry2, length);

return 0;
}
```

I was under the impression that I could use an asterisk to access the value at stored in the address the pointer points at. However, when I run this code I get the error:

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

I believe if I do:

```
temp = entry1[i];
entry1[i] = entry2[i];
entry2[i] = temp;
```

This would effectively swap the values, however, it would also swap the address' which I don't want.

Comment: Where did you call the function?

Comment: Thinks twice why in `swap()` you want to apply the dereferencing-operstor `*`.

Comment: `*(entry1 + i)` is exactly the same as `entry1[i]` .. so `*entry1[i]` is the same as `*(*(entry1 + i))`, which is one-too-many dereferences.

Comment: @yano.: `*entry1+i` is not `entry[i]` but `*(entry+i)` is.

Comment: @coderredoc I agree .. ?

Comment: @ParthianShot.: And I said that.. first is adding `i` to 0th elements...second is pointer arithemetic first and then dereferecning to get the value at that index `i`.

Comment: No offence, but when you say *"I believe if I do"*, why not just try it and see if you are right before posting a question?

Answer (score 1):

Well yes you did wrong. Correct one would be

```
  temp = entry1[i];
  entry1[i] = entry2[i];
  entry2[i] = temp;
```

This would be enough given that array decays into pointer to first element - enabling you to change the value of the array.

```
invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
```

The error itself says that you are trying to dereference an `int` not an address or some pointer value.

And for your information, `entry1[i]` is `*(entry+i)`. But you did this
`**(entry+i)`. You passed a single level pointer so it is expected that you won't dereference it twice without any error.

---

Also check the return value of `malloc` and `free` dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.